# Magento not storing to Memcached

Tags: linux, magento, memcached, e-commerce

I have installed memcached in the same server that magento is running, i have follow the instructions to configure Magento in /app/etc/local.xml

```
 <cache>
  <backend>memcached</backend>
  <memcached>
    <servers>
      <server>
        <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>
        <port><![CDATA[11211]]></port>
        <persistent><![CDATA[1]]></persistent>
        </server>
    </servers>
  </memcached>
  <compression><![CDATA[0]]></compression>
 <cache_dir><![CDATA[]]></cache_dir>
 <hashed_directory_level><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_level>
 <hashed_directory_umask><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_umask>
<file_name_prefix><![CDATA[]]></file_name_prefix>
</cache>
```

by adding this lines after the  tag. I flushed all the caches and deleted the var/cache and var/sessions but still its not writing anything to memcached.

I tried to write to memcached with a custom php script and it works fine.

any suggestion?

Comment: Something worth checking regarding Memcache

http://iamvikram.com/magento-speed-up-with-memcache/

Comment: Already tried this and is keeps writing on var/cache

Comment: To verify if Memcache is in use is very simple.

Disable all caches in the Magento admin (System > Cache Management).
Click "Flush cache storage"
Enable all caches

Then empty the content of the

./var/cache/* directory, then reload a page in the frontend and observe the contents of the above directory. If it remains empty, Memcache is being used.

Comment: Yes i have tried this and the var/cached does not remain empty, it keeps writing on that folder even after i follow this procedure.

Comment: Is memcache installed for your PHP ?

Comment: Of course i have installed the PHP support for memcached and as explained i have tried manually to save to memcached by using PHP and it works just fine.

Comment: @user1305626 hi do you get any solution for this, the same error i am getting

Comment: @DasarathiSwain to be honest i don't remember now since have been a while but i think it was smth related to the PHP handlers. Try to switch between DSO or fastCGI to get it working.

Comment: @user1305626, thank you for your replay, its working now after adding these two lines only <auto_refresh_fast_cache>0</auto_refresh_fast_cache>
            <default_priority>10</default_priority>, i don't know how